# How to give project access to a member in a group without adding manually?

Tags: gitlab

I want to add a group to a GitLab project and give all the group members developer access. When someone join the group, he/she will get the developer access automatically instead of adding him/her to the project as a developer manually.

Is there a way to do the above thing?

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem natively supported, considering the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/manage.html#add-users-to-a-group) specifies:

> Members that are not automatically added are displayed on the Invited tab.
> Users can be on this tab because they:
>
> - Have not yet accepted the invitation.
> - Are waiting for [approval from an administrator](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/moderate_users.html).
> - [Exceed the group user cap](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/manage.html#user-cap-for-groups).

You might have to script that operation, using the "[Add a member to a group or project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#add-a-member-to-a-group-or-project)"

```bash
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     --data "user_id=1&access_level=30" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/:id/members"
```

You would coupled that with a script getting the list of recent new users (like users without projects in [List Users for administrator API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#for-administrators)), run at regular interval, in order to batch such API calls.

As noted by [Bastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714893/bastian) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725662/how-to-give-project-access-to-a-member-in-a-group-without-adding-manually/73726141?noredirect=1#comment130190493_73726141), you can also setup a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) which will answer to the [Group member events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#group-member-events) (but only for GitLab Premium though)

Comment: Instead of running it in regular interval, you can use webhooks to trigger an API call.

Comment: @Bastian Good idea. I just was not sure of the type of event to monitor.